# Bar Chart in Crystal Reports on Date Parameter

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am designing a crystal report that populates data on basis of a parameter date user selects and then populates the data for a year based on that date.

The bar chart should also behave the same way by populating the data for a year, monthwise.

As an example if I select the Dec 2016 as the date in the parameter the report pulls data from Dec 2016 to Dec 2017 and the corresponding data employee wise.

The bar chart should pull these months as X Axis and then show employees data accordingly.